# prettyPhoto not grouping selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prettyphoto

I've got a prettyPhoto that I'm using and I've got all my images in and tested it. It works fine. The one catch is that it's not recognizing more than one photo at a time. When you click the icon image and the fullsize appears, it says 1/1 when there are many in an unordered list format. And clicking the forward arrow obviously refreshes the current image.

What could be the issue?

Comment: did you use rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" on opener links?

Comment: I did rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]". Is that equivalent?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AnkaT/ its working fine.

Comment: It won't work for me and I can't figure out why, it all works fine but won't go to the next photo.